# How do I solve $\int_ {-\infty}^\infty xe^{-m(x-a)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-m(x-a)^2}$$
>   where $m$ and $a$ are constants

I can solve this if the exponential is simple $e^{x^2}$ by substitution, but this one doesn't work that way as when I subsitute for $x-a$ I run into problems and often get infinity as my answer, which is wrong! So any help regarding this would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-m(x-a)^2}\,dx&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-a)e^{-m(x-a)^2}\,dx+a\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-m(x-a)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-mx^2}\,dx+a\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-mx^2}\,dx\\\\
&=a\sqrt{\pi/m}
\end{align}$$

Comment: can you explain step 2 a bit.

Comment: Long time no speak, my friend !

Comment: In Step 2, we changed made a change if variable from $x-a$ to $x$

Comment: would this still work if we had X^2 instead of x in the question? or any power of x for that matter.

Comment: @claudeleibovici Allo Calude.  Comment allez vous?

Comment: If we had $x^2$, we could have still made the same change of variable, but the analysis would proceed a bit differently.

Comment: great, Thanks mate!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.